# Process size in XP from Python

Tags: python, windows-xp

I have a python script that can approach the 2 GB process limit under Windows XP.  On a machine with 2 GB physical memory, that can pretty much lock up the machine, even if the Python script is running at below normal priority.

Is there a way in Python to find out my own process size?

Thanks,
Gerry

Comment: 640 kb should be enough for everyone :D

Comment: Even if there could be an answer to your question, you might want to take another look at your resource utilization. 2G is just too much IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
import win32process
print win32process.GetProcessMemoryInfo(win32process.GetCurrentProcess())
```

Answer (score 1):

By using psutil https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil :

```
>>> import psutil, os
>>> p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
>>> p.memory_info()
meminfo(rss=6971392, vms=47755264)
>>> p.memory_percent()
0.16821255914801228
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than worrying about limiting your process size at runtime, it might be better to figure out if all the pieces of data that you're currently storing in memory truly need to be in memory at all times.

You probably have plenty of disk space, and simply by creating some temporary files (see the [tempfile module](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html)) there should be ample opportunity to write any data you are no longer using for the current calculation to disk. You can then read it back in later when/if you need it again. This is (simplistically) how many databases work.

While disk is considered "slow" in a computational sense, it is still very fast and it is an extremely useful tool when working with large data sets. And since you are already setting the process priority to "Below Normal" it doesn't sound like speed should be a serious issue for you anyway, whereas the memory clearly is.